# Eventos: click, focusin, focusout y mouseout en una sola función

Tags: javascript

Tengo un botón en un formulario y este tiene un select personalizado.

Trato de hacer que este select dentro del botón se despliegue con evento click y evento focusin.

Y que se oculte con eventos click, evento focusout y evento mouseleave.

Me funciona con los evento click (con toggle). Y también con eventos focusin y evento focusout (usando el tab del teclado); pero no me funciona con el evento mouseleave.

Busco algo parecido a esto, tener todo en una sola función, para evitar un extenso código, porque mi proyecto en si ya es muy extenso:

```
function asi(e, foco, blur) {

    if(e) opciones.classList.toggle("activo");
    if(foco) opciones.classList.add("activo");
    if(blur) opciones.classList.remove("activo");
};

miSelect.addEventListener("click", asi); // Alternar .select de paises
miSelect.addEventListener("focusin", asi); // Abrir .select de paises
miSelect.addEventListener("focusout", asi); // Cerrar .select de paises
//opciones.addEventListener("mouseout", asi); // Cerrar .select de paises
```

```js
const perfilUser = document.getElementById("yoPerfil-user");
const perfilForm = document.getElementById("formulario-user");
const inputUser = perfilForm.querySelectorAll(".btn");

const select = document.getElementById("select");
const miSelect = document.querySelector(".grupo-btn .select");
const opciones = document.getElementById("opciones");

function inputActivo(e) { // Clases a contenedor de input form-user

    const este = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;

    if(este.classList.contains("activo")) este.classList.remove("activo");
    else este.classList.add("activo");

};

inputUser.forEach( (e) => { // Seleccionar todos los input de form-user
    e.addEventListener("focus", inputActivo);
    e.addEventListener("blur", inputActivo);
});

function asi(e, foco, blur) {

    //opciones.classList.toggle("activo");

    if(e) opciones.classList.toggle("activo");
    if(foco) opciones.classList.add("activo");
    if(blur) opciones.classList.remove("activo");
};

miSelect.addEventListener("click", asi); // Alternar .select de paises
miSelect.addEventListener("focusin", asi); // Abrir .select de paises
miSelect.addEventListener("focusout", asi); // Cerrar .select de paises
//opciones.addEventListener("mouseout", asi); // Cerrar .select de paises
```

```css
* {
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent
} *, ::before, ::after {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.formulario-user {
    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 5px
} .formulario-user.activo {
    right: 0
} .yoPerfil-user.fuera {
    right: -100%
}

.grupo-form, .grupo-btn {
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%
} .grupo-form {
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc
} .grupo-form:hover, .grupo-form.activo {
    border-bottom-color: green
} .grupo-btn {
    align-items: center
}

.grupo-form label {
    cursor: pointer
} .grupo-form label, .grupo-btn .yo-bi {
    color: #ccc;
    transition: .3s
} .grupo-form:hover label, .grupo-form.activo label, .grupo-btn:hover .yo-bi, .grupo-form.activo .yo-bi {
    color: green
}

.grupo-btn .select {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%
} .grupo-btn .select:hover, .grupo-btn .select.activo {
    background-color: green
} .grupo-btn .select .contenido-select {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: .90rem;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #000
}

.grupo-btn.contraseña .btn {
    width: 50%
}

.grupo-btn .opciones {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 145px;
    max-height: 300px;
    border-radius: .10rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transform: scale(0);
    background: rgba(0 128 0 / 0.5);
    backdrop-filter: blur(2px)
} .grupo-btn .opciones.activo {
    transform: scale(1);
    animation: fadeIn .20s forwards
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {transform: translateY(50%) scale(0)}
    to {transform: translateY(0) scale(1)}
} .grupo-btn .opciones .opcion {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .30rem .30rem;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: .80rem
} .grupo-btn .opciones .opcion:hover {
    background-color: green
}

.grupo-btn .select .contenido-select img, .grupo-btn .opciones .opcion img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 15px;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 5px
}

.grupo-btn .btn, .grupo-btn .opciones .opcion {
    color: #fff
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="#" class="formulario-user" id="formulario-user">

        <div class="grupo-form">
            <label for="nombreUser">Nombre para el perfil</label>
            <div class="grupo-btn">
                <span class="yo-bi bi-person-fill"></span>
                <input type="text" class="btn btn-sm" id="nombreUser" placeholder="nombre">
            </div>
            <p class="aviso" id="infoNombre"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="grupo-form">
            <label for="select">Número de teléfono</label>
            <div class="grupo-btn">
                <span class="yo-bi bi-phone-fill"></span>
                
                <button class="btn btn-sm select" id="miTelefono">
                    
                    <div class="contenido-select" id="select">
                        <span class="titulo bi-chevron-down bi-r-5">Seleccionar... </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="opciones" id="opciones">
                        <div class="opcion" valor="986 234 123">
                            <img src="fotoPerfil/Narciso.jpg">
                            <span>Paraguay +595</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="opcion">
                            <img src="img/spain.png" alt="">
                            <span class="titulo">España 3656</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="opcion">
                            <img src="img/colombia.png" alt="">
                            <span class="titulo">Colombia 4574</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </button>

                <input type="tel" class="btn btn-sm" id="formTelefono" placeholder=" número">
            </div>
            <p class="aviso" id="infoTelefono"></p>
        </div>
        
    </form>
```

Comment: Prueba con `miSelect.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() { asi(null, null, true); });`

Comment: Sigo teniendo el problema. Cuando clikeo el botón, se abre y se cierra solo, y no me funciona con preventDefault(). Al parecer hay un conflicto en la función, porque todos los diferentes eventos apunta a la misma función, aunque haya diferentes condiciones

Comment: El problema se genera entre el evento click y focusin. No puedo solucionar ese conflicto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese caos de eventos nunca resulta bien.

En el fondo lo que tu quieres hacer es un Dropdowlist, esto lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera.

El componente se compone de 2 partes

- El elemento que al presionarlo abre un modal
- El modal con la lista de opciones

Lo más simple es que ambos elementos sean hermanos y no como lo estas haciendo tu que el modal es hijo del primero (luego te explico la razón)

*Otra cosa importante es que si vas a usar un `<button>` dentro de un `form` es necesario colocar el `type="button"` para que no active el submit*

Luego está función hace lo que necesitas:

```
const miSelect = document.querySelector("#select");
const opciones = document.getElementById("opciones");


function ClickSelect() {
   if(!opciones.classList.contains("activo"))
    {
      opciones.classList.add("activo");
      document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        opciones.classList.remove("activo");

      }, {once : true, capture:true});
    }
}


miSelect.addEventListener("click", ClickSelect);
```

Explicación:

- Cuando el modal está abierto y se presiona el botón no hace nada (tiene la clase `active`
- Si está cerrado, es decir NO tiene la clase active

  - Lo abre (agrega la clase active)
  - Agrega un evento a todo el documento, el cual al hacer click en cualquier parte cierra el modal

Este evento lo seteamos con

- once : true -> Para que se borre luego de haber sido disparado la primera vez
- capture:true -> Para que se ejecute luego de haber hecho del primer click original.

La explicación de porque el botón y el modal deben ser hermanos, es para que el evento `document.addEventListener("click",` que cierra el modal no se solape con el evento `miSelect.addEventListener("click"`.

Demo:

```js
const miSelect = document.querySelector("#select");
const opciones = document.getElementById("opciones");


function ClickSelect() {
   if(!opciones.classList.contains("activo"))
    {
      opciones.classList.add("activo");
      document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        opciones.classList.remove("activo");

      }, {once : true, capture:true});
    }
};

miSelect.addEventListener("click", ClickSelect);
```

```css
* {
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent
} *, ::before, ::after {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.formulario-user {
    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 5px
} .formulario-user.activo {
    right: 0
} .yoPerfil-user.fuera {
    right: -100%
}

.grupo-form, .grupo-btn {
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%
} .grupo-form {
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc
} .grupo-form:hover, .grupo-form.activo {
    border-bottom-color: green
} .grupo-btn {
    align-items: center
}

.grupo-form label {
    cursor: pointer
} .grupo-form label, .grupo-btn .yo-bi {
    color: #ccc;
    transition: .3s
} .grupo-form:hover label, .grupo-form.activo label, .grupo-btn:hover .yo-bi, .grupo-form.activo .yo-bi {
    color: green
}

.grupo-btn .select {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%
} .grupo-btn .select:hover, .grupo-btn .select.activo {
    background-color: green
} .grupo-btn .select .contenido-select {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: .90rem;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #000
}

.grupo-btn.contraseña .btn {
    width: 50%
}

.grupo-btn .opciones {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 145px;
    max-height: 300px;
    border-radius: .10rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transform: scale(0);
    background: rgba(0 128 0 / 0.5);
    backdrop-filter: blur(2px)
} .grupo-btn .opciones.activo {
    transform: scale(1);
    animation: fadeIn .20s forwards
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {transform: translateY(50%) scale(0)}
    to {transform: translateY(0) scale(1)}
} .grupo-btn .opciones .opcion {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .30rem .30rem;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: .80rem
} .grupo-btn .opciones .opcion:hover {
    background-color: green
}

.grupo-btn .select .contenido-select img, .grupo-btn .opciones .opcion img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 15px;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 5px
}

.grupo-btn .btn, .grupo-btn .opciones .opcion {
    color: #fff
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form action="#" class="formulario-user" id="formulario-user">

        <div class="grupo-form">
            <label for="nombreUser">Nombre para el perfil</label>
            <div class="grupo-btn">
                <span class="yo-bi bi-person-fill"></span>
                <input type="text" class="btn btn-sm" id="nombreUser" placeholder="nombre">
            </div>
            <p class="aviso" id="infoNombre"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="grupo-form">
            <label for="select">Número de teléfono</label>
            <div class="grupo-btn">
                <span class="yo-bi bi-phone-fill"></span>
                

                    
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="select">
                        <span style="display:flex" class="titulo bi-chevron-down bi-r-5">Seleccionar... </span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="opciones" id="opciones">
                        <div class="opcion" valor="986 234 123">
                            <img src="fotoPerfil/Narciso.jpg">
                            <span>Paraguay +595</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="opcion">
                            <img src="img/spain.png" alt="">
                            <span class="titulo">España 3656</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="opcion">
                            <img src="img/colombia.png" alt="">
                            <span class="titulo">Colombia 4574</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
        

                <input type="tel" class="btn btn-sm" id="formTelefono" placeholder=" número">
            </div>
            <p class="aviso" id="infoTelefono"></p>
        </div>
        
    </form>
```

Comment: Y como quedaría el evento focus en este caso? Necesito el focusin para usar solamente el teclado (para recorrer entre input y el botón miSelect con tab)

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz No entiendo que tiene que ver, tu quieres emular un select o es otra cosa?

Comment: Si, un Select, que se abre sobre el evento focusin o click. Pero tú código me ayudó un poco y solucione de una forma un poco diferente.

Comment: Es que un select normal de toda la vida no se abre cuando le haces focus

Comment: Si, por eso necesitaba el boton para usar su evento de foco

Answer (score 0):

Logré unir los cuatro eventos (como quiero) en una sola función.

Usando la tecla TAB recorro los imput y el botón. Cuando el botón es focusin, se despliega su menú select personalizado. Cuando es focusout, se oculta. Por eso debía ser un botón, para usar su evento focus.

También cuando se le da click al botón, se puede desplegar u ocultar su menú select personalizado.

Gracias a la respuesta pude completar, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```js
const perfilForm = document.getElementById("formulario-user");
const inputUser = perfilForm.querySelectorAll(".btn");
const select = document.getElementById("select");
const selecto = document.querySelector(".selecto");
const miSelect = document.querySelector(".grupo-btn .select");
const opciones = document.getElementById("opciones");
const miOpciones = document.querySelectorAll("#opciones .opcion");


function inputActivo(e) { // Clases a contenedor de input form-user

  const este = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;

  if (este.classList.contains("activo")) este.classList.remove("activo");
  else este.classList.add("activo");

};

inputUser.forEach((e) => { // Seleccionar todos los input de form-user
  e.addEventListener("focus", inputActivo);
  e.addEventListener("blur", inputActivo);
});

function yoSelect() {

  if (!opciones.classList.contains("activo")) {

    opciones.classList.add("activo");
    miSelect.classList.add("activo");

    document.addEventListener("click", function() {
      opciones.classList.remove("activo");
      miSelect.classList.remove("activo");
    }, {
      once: true,
      capture: true
    });
  }

  function opcionFuera() {
    opciones.classList.remove("activo");
    miSelect.classList.remove("activo");
  }

  miSelect.addEventListener("focusout", opcionFuera);
  selecto.addEventListener("mouseleave", opcionFuera);
};

miSelect.addEventListener("click", yoSelect);
miSelect.addEventListener("focusin", yoSelect);
```

```css
.formulario-user {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: calc(100% - 115px);
  padding: 0 5px
}

.grupo-form,
.grupo-btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%
}

.grupo-form {
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey
}

.grupo-form:hover,
.grupo-form.activo {
  border-bottom-color: green
}

.grupo-btn {
  align-items: center
}

.grupo-form label {
  cursor: pointer
}

.grupo-form label,
.grupo-btn .yo-bi {
  color: grey;
  transition: .3s
}

.grupo-form:hover label,
.grupo-form.activo label,
.grupo-btn:hover .yo-bi,
.grupo-form.activo .yo-bi {
  color: green
}

.grupo-form.error label,
.grupo-form.error .yo-bi {
  color: brown
}

.grupo-btn .selecto {
  display: block;
  position: relative
}

.grupo-btn .select .titulo {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%
}

.grupo-btn .select:hover,
.grupo-btn .select.activo {
  background-color: lightgreen
}

.grupo-btn .select .contenido-select {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: .90rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: "000
}

.grupo-btn.contraseña .btn {
  width: 50%
}

.grupo-btn .opciones {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 145px;
  max-height: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: .10rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: scale(0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, .5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px)
}

.grupo-btn .opciones.activo {
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: fadeIn .20s forwards
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    transform: translateY(50%) scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1)
  }
}

.opciones .opcion {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .30rem .30rem;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: .80rem
}

.opciones .opcion:hover,
.opciones .opcion.activo {
  color: green;
  background-color: red
}

.grupo-btn .select .contenido-select img,
.grupo-btn .opciones .opcion img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 5px
}

.formInput-info {
  position: absolute;
  right: .50rem;
  color: var(--colorRojo);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .3s
}

.grupo-form.error .formInput-info {
  opacity: 1
}

.grupo-btn .btn,
.btn-sm::-webkit-file-upload-button,
.btn-sm::file-selector-button,
.grupo-btn .opciones .opcion {
  border: 0;
  color: #000
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="formulario-user" id="formulario-user">

  <div class="grupo-form">
    <label for="nombreUser">Nombre para el perfil</label>
    <div class="grupo-btn">
      <span class="yo-bi bi-person-fill"></span>
      <input type="text" class="btn btn-sm" placeholder="nombre">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grupo-form">
    <label for="select">Número de teléfono</label>
    <div class="grupo-btn">
      <span class="yo-bi bi-phone-fill"></span>

      <div class="selecto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm select" id="miTelefono">
                        <span class="titulo bi-chevron-up bi-r-5"> Seleccionar... </span>
                    </button>
        <div class="opciones" id="opciones">
          <div class="opcion" valor="986 234 123">
            <img src="fotoPerfil/Narciso.jpg">
            <span>Paraguay +595</span>
          </div>
          <div class="opcion">
            <img src="img/spain.png" alt="">
            <span class="titulo">España 3656</span>
          </div>
          <div class="opcion">
            <img src="img/colombia.png" alt="">
            <span class="titulo">Colombia 4574</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <input type="tel" class="btn btn-sm" id="formTelefono" placeholder=" número">
    </div>
    <p class="aviso" id="infoTelefono"></p>
  </div>

</form>
```